# .net static object lifecycle

Tags: c#, static, singleton, clr, lifecycle

I've got a DAL library with a repository static class; it's initialized via singleton pattern (static constructor).  There is website that uses this DAL library, and a windows service project in the same solution.

As far as know, there would be two instances of the singleton object, one in each domain of site and WINservice.  Is that right?

For the web site app, after some idle time, the domain in unloaded, and so the repo class will be unloaded too, right?

And last question about the winservice: as far as know this domain will never be unloaded, while the service is running, so that the repo object will remain in memory?

PS: What would happen, if I create a subclass object, e.g. worker for winservice, which will use the repo class inside of it.

```
using (var worker = new worker())
{
    //some DAL manipulations
}
```

Would the repo object be destroyed once I leave the worker context?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: AFAIK, you can turn off web app unloading.  It would be advisable in your case.

Comment: You should ask one question at a time, not two, mostly unrelated questions.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor, ok but this is more important to me to understand what should be default behaviour.

Comment: @svick, sorry but, all this question are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as know, there would be two instances of the singleton object,
>   one in each domain of site and WINservice. Is that right?

Yes

> For the web site app, after some idle time, the domain in unloaded,
>   and so the repo class will be unloaded too, right?

Yes (the rules for recycling the app pool can be setup in IIS)

> And last question about the winservice: as far as know this domain
>   will never be unloaded, while the service is running, so that the repo
>   object will remain in memory?

Yes

> Would the repo object be destroyed once I leave the worker context?

No (unless you dispose of it of course)

Comment: Tnaks, I have limited connections to db, so this information is really  helpful for me.

Comment: Disposing an object has nothing to do with actually destroying it. That's the work of the garbage collector and you can't force it to collect some object.

Comment: @svick since he is using the `using` statement in the question for the worker thread i'm pretty sure he meant if the repo object would be disposed (not destroyed as in collected by the GB which would make no sense in this context) with the worker thread and my answer was that it would not unless he did it explicitly.